# Swift 3: Int is not convertible to Bool in bitwise operation

Tags: swift

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but here's the trivial code that's breaking:

```
if 10 & (1<<18) {
    return
}
```

This gives me:

> 'Int' is not convertible to 'Bool'

What is wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unlike in C where you can write...

```
if (x) { }
```

... which is really a non-zero check:

```
if (x != 0) { }
```

You must test for a boolean condition in Swift. Add `!= 0` to your statement:

```
if 10 & (1<<18) != 0 {
    return
}
```

Comment: And in this case, it will never be true and the compiler will probably optimize the whole `if` statement out of existence.

Comment: I thought swift is smart. Dumb me!

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4** : **Check that**

1. Your method has a **correct return type** which the caller is expecting 
   eg: `func yourMethod() -> Bool`
2. The caller method has **parentheses ()** at the end `yourMethod()`